# Color Contrast Testing procedure for Loading Spinner(Gif)

Tags: html, colors, accessibility

I am doing Color Contrast validation for one Application.Please let me know how to validate the Loading spinner icon(GIF file).
Please let me know the procedure to validate static/dynamic(Gif) icons from color contrast perspective.

Comment: add your Code here you have tried out

Comment: Hi Kaushal,
This is not related to any coding issue.I am looking for the procedure on how to do color contrast testing for icons

Comment: oh. i am sorry . i suppose to expected that there is some html code here.

Comment: By "spinner icon", I assume you mean an icon that indicates that something is (still) in progress? If yes, could you please edit the question's title? The function of an image or icon makes a difference with regard to what it needs to comply with (in WCAG).

Answer (score 0):

The spinner does not need to pass Colour Contrast - it is an informational image.

Obviously without seeing the spinner in place I cannot comment if it is clear enough but provided it isn't white on white the fact that something changes on the page should be sufficient.

Movement is also much more clear than static text so bear that in mind.

For compliance - Colour contrast only really applies to text (although I love the fact you are thinking about it on your loader).

What you may want to look at is `ARIA` attributes to update screen reader users that something is happening.

If you are at all unsure you could use an inline SVG spinner rather than a GIF (plus it will be one less HTTP request so helps with speed :-) ) as then you can set the colours via CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the color of the spinner and the background color in contrast color tools like this one and see if it fails the minimum contrast:

https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/